# How to know hardware difference directly from standard names and references?

Tags: dvd

Hardware parts always come with what **seems to be standard naming**.

Example for DVD burners :

- Samsung SE-S084
- Panasonic SW-9587-S

Is there some standard understanding of these letters ? For example, is the difference between Panasonic SW-9587-S and SW-9587-C the same as any DVD burner called XXX-S and XXX-C ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Each manufacturer has its Marketing-Droids who do invent these numbers out-of-the-blue for each product.

In a product series a higher number may indicate better performance, but that's no rule, just a conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no such standard.

Names might be standardised by brand, but even that's only the decision of the company, not a requirement.

Comment: OK thanks. At least, does a different last letter mean the difference is "less important" that a different number ?
For example, should we expect Panasonic SW-9587-S and SW-9587-C to be technically similar ?

Comment: Not necessary. There is no general rule.